# How exactly do I resolve this "unwrapping" error?

Tags: swift, option-type

I am learning to code and I am trying to make a POS terminal- type code:

```
var stockCount = ["Pepsi": 450, "Sprite": 300, "Oreo Dairy MIlk": 3]
enum stockError : Error {
    case NotEnough
}

func cart(item: String, quantity: Int) throws -> Int {
    for (item, stock) in stockCount{
        guard quantity > stockCount[item] else {
            throw stockError.NotEnough
        }
    }   
}
```

For this, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR at line 32, col 30: value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
                guard quantity > stockCount[item] else {
                                           ^
                                                 !
```

Please help!!

Comment: If you're just trying to see if you have enough items in stock, why are you looping over the entire stock?  Just make sure `quantity <= stockCount[item] ?? 0`.

Comment: Or better still, add an `invalidItem` case to your `StockError` (type names should be `UpperCamelCase`, everything else `lowerCamelCase`) for when there's no value in your dictionary for a given key.

Comment: if makes no sence to to loop over `stockCount` and also shadow the parameter `item` with the loop variable `item` which can be very buggy sometimes

Comment: i think you mix a test with logic implementation

Comment: i don't unterstand what goal of your function.

Answer (score 1):

`stockCount` is a Dictionary. When you access a dictionary's value via a key, it is possible that the key doesn't exist so the resulting value is optional.

In other words, `stockCount[item]` returns an optional value. You can't use the `<` operator (or other operators) with an optional value.

There are a few solutions but the most direct, since you are using the `for` loop and getting each key and value directly, is to change that line to:

```
guard quantity > stock else {
```

`stock` is the current value of `stockCount[item]` but it won't be optional since the `for` loop is only giving you actual existing values from the dictionary.

Comment: You can use `==` with an optional ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that.

Solution 1 (recommended in your case): directly compare to `stock`

```
guard quantity > stock else {
    throw stockError.NotEnough
}
```

Solution 2: manually check for nil before doing the comparison

```
guard stockCountItem = stockCount[item], quantity > stockCountItem else {
    throw stockError.NotEnough
}
```

Solution 3: provide a fallback value to always do the comparison

```
guard quantity > (stockCount[item] ?? 0) else {
    throw stockError.NotEnough
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix a technical bug is easy. shown in other answers. but i don't get a clue what is your goal with your function. the name of the function gives no clue.

#### Logic Error

if you check if is enough in stock then this is wrong:

```
guard quantity > stock else {
    throw stockError.NotEnough
}
```

it should be when you want more then in stock throw an error

```
guard quantity < stock else {
    throw stockError.NotEnough
}
```

#### Current Code

ok lets analyse:

you have a parameter `item` and `quantity` and you expect a `Int` as return type. what should the return type be?

```
var stockCount = ["Pepsi": 450, "Sprite": 300, "Oreo Dairy MIlk": 3]

enum StockError : Error {
    case NotEnough
}

func cart(item: String, quantity: Int) throws -> Int {
    print("Parameters item: \(item), quantity: \(quantity)")
    for (item, stock) in stockCount{
        print("compare for \(item): \(quantity) > \(stock)")
        guard quantity > stock else {
            throw StockError.NotEnough
        }
    }
    return 0
}

do {
    let result = try cart(item: "Pepsi", quantity: 200)
    print("Result: \(result)")

} catch let error as StockError  {
    print(error)
}
```

with this result

```
Parameters item: Pepsi, quantity: 500
compare for Sprite: 500 > 300
compare for Pepsi: 500 > 450
compare for Oreo Dairy MIlk: 500 > 3
Result: 0

Parameters item: Pepsi, quantity: 450
compare for Sprite: 450 > 300
compare for Pepsi: 450 > 450
Error: NotEnough

Parameters item: Pepsi, quantity: 400
compare for Sprite: 400 > 300
compare for Pepsi: 400 > 450
Error: NotEnough
```

this result makes no sense.

#### Refactoring

i would write this function like this:

```
enum StockError : Error {
    case ItemNotExist(item: String)
    case NotEnough(item: String,currentCount: Int, missingCount: Int)
}

// Check Item if available and return remainig quantity
func checkItem(item: String, quantity: Int) throws -> Int {
    guard let stockItemCount = stockCount[item] else {
        throw StockError.ItemNotExist(item: item)
    }
    let remaining = stockItemCount - quantity
    guard remaining >= 0 else {
        throw StockError.NotEnough(item: item,currentCount: stockItemCount, missingCount: remaining)
    }
    return remaining
}
```

#### My Full Playground with Logging and some Samples

i had some time and i played a little with your idea and here is my Playground

i am used:

- an Logger where i can set the LogLevel
- use very detailed logging - in production code this is not needed
- checkItems to check items
- checkCart to check a cart
- sampleCarts to run the function against some sample carts to see the results

set the LogLevel as you like:

```
let logger = Logger(.verbose)
```

here is my Playgound - happy plaing :)

```
var stockCount = ["Pepsi": 450, "Sprite": 300, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]


class Logger {

    let currentLogLevel: LogLevel

    init(_ logLevel: LogLevel){
        self.currentLogLevel = logLevel
    }

    enum LogLevel: Int {
        case info = 1
        case verbose = 2
    }

    func log(_ object: Any, logLevel: LogLevel = .verbose){
        if logLevel.rawValue <= currentLogLevel.rawValue {
            print(object)
        } else {
            //nothing
        }
    }

    func info(_ object: Any){
        log(object, logLevel: .info)
    }
    func verbose(_ object: Any){
        log(object, logLevel: .verbose)
    }
}


// Set LogLevel for logger

//let logger = Logger(.info)
let logger = Logger(.verbose)

enum StockError : Error {
    case ItemNotExist(item: String)
    case NotEnough(item: String,currentCount: Int, missingCount: Int)
}

// Check Item if available and return remainig quantity
func checkItem(item: String, quantity: Int) throws -> Int {
    logger.verbose("    checkItem: Parameters: item: '\(item)', quantity: \(quantity)")

    guard let stockItemCount = stockCount[item] else {
        throw StockError.ItemNotExist(item: item)
    }
    logger.verbose("    checkItem: available items for '\(item)': \(stockItemCount)")

    let remaining = stockItemCount - quantity
    logger.verbose("    checkItem: remaining items for '\(item)': \(remaining)")
    guard remaining >= 0 else {
        throw StockError.NotEnough(item: item,currentCount: stockItemCount, missingCount: remaining)
    }

    logger.verbose("    checkItem: Result: Remaining: \(remaining)")
    return remaining
}

func cartCheck(cart: [String:Int]) throws -> [String:Int]{
    logger.verbose("cartCheck: Parameters: cart: \(cart)\n")
    var result: [String:Int] = [:]
    for cartItem in cart{
        logger.verbose("  cartCheck: check for cartItem: '\(cartItem.key)', quantity: \(cartItem.value)")
        let checkResult = try checkItem(item: cartItem.key, quantity: cartItem.value)
        logger.verbose("  cartCheck: for '\(cartItem.key)' remaining: \(checkResult)\n")

        result[cartItem.key] = checkResult
    }
    logger.verbose("cartCheck: Result: \(result)\n")
    return result
}


func itemSamples(){

    do {
        let result = try checkItem(item: "Pepsi", quantity: 1)
        logger.verbose("Result: \(result)")
    } catch let error  {
        logger.verbose("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

func cartSamples(){

    let sampleCarts = [
        [
            "description": "normal Cart",
            "cart": ["Pepsi":300, "Sprite":200]
        ],
        [
            "description": "normal Cart",
            "cart": ["Pepsi":100, "Oreo Dairy Milk":2]
        ],
        [
            "description": "normal Cart - empty Stock",
            "cart": ["Pepsi":450, "Sprite": 300, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
        ],
        [
            "description": "Fanta is not available",
            "cart": ["Pepsi":100, "Fanta":100]
        ],
        [
            "description": "not enougth Sprite",
            "cart": ["Pepsi":100, "Sprite":500]
        ],
        [
            "description": "too much oreo",
            "cart": ["Oreo Dairy Milk":100, "Sprite":20]
        ]

    ]

    for sampleCart in sampleCarts{
        logger.info("\n\nsample for: \(sampleCart["description"]!)")
        logger.info(" for stock: \(stockCount)")
        logger.info(" with cart: \(sampleCart["cart"]!)")


        do {
            let result = try cartCheck( cart: sampleCart["cart"]! as! [String : Int])
            logger.info("    Result: \(result)")
        } catch let error  {
            logger.verbose("")
            logger.info("     Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


itemSamples()
cartSamples()
```

result for LogLevel `.info`:

```
sample for: normal Cart
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 200, "Pepsi": 300]
    Result: ["Sprite": 100, "Pepsi": 150]


sample for: normal Cart
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Pepsi": 100, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 2]
    Result: ["Pepsi": 350, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 1]


sample for: normal Cart - empty Stock
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
    Result: ["Sprite": 0, "Pepsi": 0, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 0]


sample for: Fanta is not available
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Fanta": 100, "Pepsi": 100]
     Error: ItemNotExist("Fanta")


sample for: not enougth Sprite
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 500, "Pepsi": 100]
     Error: NotEnough("Sprite", 300, -200)


sample for: too much oreo
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 20, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 100]
     Error: NotEnough("Oreo Dairy Milk", 3, -97)
```

result for LogLevel `.verbose`:

```
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Pepsi', quantity: 1
    checkItem: available items for 'Pepsi': 450
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Pepsi': 449
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 449
Result: 449


sample for: normal Cart
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 200, "Pepsi": 300]
cartCheck: Parameters: cart: ["Sprite": 200, "Pepsi": 300]

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Sprite', quantity: 200
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Sprite', quantity: 200
    checkItem: available items for 'Sprite': 300
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Sprite': 100
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 100
  cartCheck: for 'Sprite' remaining: 100

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Pepsi', quantity: 300
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Pepsi', quantity: 300
    checkItem: available items for 'Pepsi': 450
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Pepsi': 150
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 150
  cartCheck: for 'Pepsi' remaining: 150

cartCheck: Result: ["Sprite": 100, "Pepsi": 150]

    Result: ["Sprite": 100, "Pepsi": 150]


sample for: normal Cart
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Pepsi": 100, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 2]
cartCheck: Parameters: cart: ["Pepsi": 100, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 2]

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Pepsi', quantity: 100
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Pepsi', quantity: 100
    checkItem: available items for 'Pepsi': 450
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Pepsi': 350
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 350
  cartCheck: for 'Pepsi' remaining: 350

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Oreo Dairy Milk', quantity: 2
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Oreo Dairy Milk', quantity: 2
    checkItem: available items for 'Oreo Dairy Milk': 3
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Oreo Dairy Milk': 1
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 1
  cartCheck: for 'Oreo Dairy Milk' remaining: 1

cartCheck: Result: ["Pepsi": 350, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 1]

    Result: ["Pepsi": 350, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 1]


sample for: normal Cart - empty Stock
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
cartCheck: Parameters: cart: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Sprite', quantity: 300
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Sprite', quantity: 300
    checkItem: available items for 'Sprite': 300
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Sprite': 0
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 0
  cartCheck: for 'Sprite' remaining: 0

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Pepsi', quantity: 450
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Pepsi', quantity: 450
    checkItem: available items for 'Pepsi': 450
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Pepsi': 0
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 0
  cartCheck: for 'Pepsi' remaining: 0

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Oreo Dairy Milk', quantity: 3
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Oreo Dairy Milk', quantity: 3
    checkItem: available items for 'Oreo Dairy Milk': 3
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Oreo Dairy Milk': 0
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 0
  cartCheck: for 'Oreo Dairy Milk' remaining: 0

cartCheck: Result: ["Sprite": 0, "Pepsi": 0, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 0]

    Result: ["Sprite": 0, "Pepsi": 0, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 0]


sample for: Fanta is not available
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Fanta": 100, "Pepsi": 100]
cartCheck: Parameters: cart: ["Fanta": 100, "Pepsi": 100]

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Fanta', quantity: 100
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Fanta', quantity: 100

     Error: ItemNotExist("Fanta")


sample for: not enougth Sprite
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 500, "Pepsi": 100]
cartCheck: Parameters: cart: ["Sprite": 500, "Pepsi": 100]

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Sprite', quantity: 500
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Sprite', quantity: 500
    checkItem: available items for 'Sprite': 300
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Sprite': -200

     Error: NotEnough("Sprite", 300, -200)


sample for: too much oreo
 for stock: ["Sprite": 300, "Pepsi": 450, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 3]
 with cart: ["Sprite": 20, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 100]
cartCheck: Parameters: cart: ["Sprite": 20, "Oreo Dairy Milk": 100]

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Sprite', quantity: 20
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Sprite', quantity: 20
    checkItem: available items for 'Sprite': 300
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Sprite': 280
    checkItem: Result: Remaining: 280
  cartCheck: for 'Sprite' remaining: 280

  cartCheck: check for cartItem: 'Oreo Dairy Milk', quantity: 100
    checkItem: Parameters: item: 'Oreo Dairy Milk', quantity: 100
    checkItem: available items for 'Oreo Dairy Milk': 3
    checkItem: remaining items for 'Oreo Dairy Milk': -97

     Error: NotEnough("Oreo Dairy Milk", 3, -97)
```